# Finding the average of a column with a variable condition in the where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table named Data:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 50 | 10 |

And I want to find the first 'id' index (nFirst) where the average of the 'value' column is above some pre-given value ('avg'). In other words I want to solve for nFirst. I have this query

```
SELECT AVG(value)
FROM Data
WHERE id < nFirst AND AVG(value) > avg
GROUP BY id;
```

The above query has the general idea of what I'd like to calculate but it obviously won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the **running** average of each row?

Comment: Maybe something like this?

SELECT AVG(value) as average
FROM Data
GROUP BY id, value
HAVING average > some_value
LIMIT 1

Comment: @forpas yes, the running average of each row would solve this

Answer (score 0):

For MySql 8.0+ use `AVG()` window function to get the running average for each row and filter out the rows with less than the average that you want and finally pick the smallest `id` of the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id, AVG(value) OVER (ORDER BY id) avg_value  
  FROM Data
) d
WHERE avg_value > ?
ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

For previous versions use a self join and aggregation:

```
SELECT d1.id, AVG(d2.value) avg_value
FROM Data d1 INNER JOIN Data d2
ON d2.id <= d1.id
GROUP BY d1.id
HAVING avg_value > ?
ORDER BY d1.id LIMIT 1;
```

Replace `?` with the average value that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have DB version 8.0+, then use `SUM() OVER ()` window function, presuming all id values are *consecutively incrementing* as in the shared example data set, in such a way

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS least_id
  FROM
  (SELECT id, SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY id)/id AS avg_
     FROM Data) AS d
 WHERE avg_ > avg --> substitute 5 as an example value for the parameter "avg"
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6f7d1ffe53d601b0d09e00181333e5a)</kbd>